Error: Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component
Estoy creando una app con react native usando expo, pero me esta dando un error con expo router. Intento que en la initial screen al apretar entrar te envie a index2(el nombre es hasta que arregle el problema) pero cada vez que me lleva a esa ruta index2 me retorna el error:

Error: Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component. Ensure the Root Layout component is rendering a Slot, or other navigator on the first render., js engine: hermes

El codigo de _layout.tsx es el siguiente:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Stack, Slot } from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

// Components
import CustomHeaderNav from '@/components/customHeaderNav';
import InitialScreen from './initialScreen';

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from 'expo-router';

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: 'index2',
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return <RootLayoutNav />;
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const [isSignedIn] = useState(true);

  return (
    isSignedIn ?
    (
      <InitialScreen />
    ) : (
      <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="index2" 
      options={{ 
        headerShown: true,
        header: () => <CustomHeaderNav />,
      }} />
      </Stack>
    )
  );
}


y el de initialscreen es:
// React
import React, {useState} from 'react';

// React-native
import { useRouter, Link } from 'expo-router';

// React-native
import { 
  View, 
  Text, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Image, 
  AppState,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

// Supabase
// import { supabase } from '../lib/supabase';

// Images
// const upperCircle = require('../assets/right-circle.png');
// const mountain = require('../assets/mountain.png');
// const footerIcon = require('../assets/footer-icon.png');

// Safe area insets
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const InitialScreen = () => {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const route = useRouter();

  // AppState.addEventListener('change', (state) => {
  //   if (state === 'active') {
  //     supabase.auth.startAutoRefresh()
  //   } else {
  //     supabase.auth.stopAutoRefresh()
  //   }
  // })
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* <Image source={upperCircle} style={styles.rightImage} /> */}
      
      <View style={[styles.middleContainer, {paddingLeft: insets.left + 10, paddingRight: insets.right + 10}]}>
        <View style={styles.imageAndTextContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.createText}>
            ¡Bienvenido/a a GREENNVI! 
          </Text>

          <Text style={styles.smallText}>
            Explora acciones, iniciativas y ayuda a la comunidad. ¡Disfruta tu viaje con nosotros!
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      
      <View style={[styles.buttonContainer, {paddingBottom: insets.bottom + 20}]}>
        {/* <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={() => route.push('/home')}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Entrar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> */}
        <Link href='/index2' style={styles.loginButton} asChild>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Entrar</Text>
        </Link>
        <View style={styles.registerButton}>
          <Text style={styles.registerText}>Registrarse</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      {/* <Image source={footerIcon} style={styles.footerIcon} /> */}
    </View>
  );
}

export default InitialScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  rightImage: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: 300,
    width: 300
  },
  middleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  imageAndTextContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  mountainImage: {
    height: 200,
    width: 400
  },
  createText: {
    fontWeight: '900',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#007472',
    textAlign: 'center',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
  smallText: {
    fontWeight: '500',
    fontSize: 17,
    color: '#007472',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: 350,
    marginTop: 20
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: 40,
    zIndex: 2
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#007472',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  loginText: {
    color: '#FFF',
    fontWeight: '700'
  },
  registerButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#007472',
  },
  registerText: {
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#007472'
  },
  footerIcon: {
    height: 300,
    width: 200,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 1
  },
});



Lo que está pasando es que las rutas no se están montando cuando haces esto
 return (
    isSignedIn ?
    (
      <InitialScreen />
    ) : (
      <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="index2" 
      options={{ 
        headerShown: true,
        header: () => <CustomHeaderNav />,
      }} />
      </Stack>
    )
  );

entonces la ruta index2 no existe tienes que crear una ruta para tu primer componente o hacer que cuando presiones en entrar cambie isSignedIn a false y ahi ya se muestra index2
